# ModuleNotFoundError: folder structure problem in my scrapy project?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and vscode, and my project was working perfectly fine until I decided to get tidy with the folders before uploading on github . After that, whole project is not working anymore. I am pretty sure I messed up the folder structure:

```
└── real_estate/
    ├── project1/
    │   ├── project1_scrapy/
    │   │   ├── spiders/
    │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   │   └── project1__spider.py
    │   │   ├── items.py
    │   │   ├── middlewares.py
    │   │   ├── pipelines.py
    │   │   └── settings.py
    │   └── scrapy.cfg
    └── project2/
        ├── project2_scrapy/
        │   ├── spiders/
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
        │   │   └── project2__spider.py
        │   ├── items.py
        │   ├── middlewares.py
        │   ├── pipelines.py
        │   └── settings.py
        └── scrapy.cfg
```

I am running to crawler on the folder of scrapy.cfg. Still getting the following error:

```
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project1'
```

Comment: How are you executing it, and from which folder?

Comment: so to execute the project_spider.py, I run "scrapy crawl spider name" from folder 'project1'. Same goes for project2, as both scrapy configs are found on those folders.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project1'` because you `can't change/rename` the project that once you've created by the command `scrapy startproject` that would be

```
project1
 project1
```

but in your case.it's

```
project1
    project1_scrapy
```

It seems to be clear that you have renamed/added `_scrapy` with project1 that's why scrapy can't find the `project1` and shows the mentioned error.

If you go to your project's settings.py file then you can see your project name like :

```
BOT_NAME = 'project1'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['project1.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'project1.spiders'
```

So remove the `_scrapy`  from `project1_scrapy` or create new project and never change/rename the project or make correct spider module name from settings.fy file according to the project folder. If you change something like bot name/spider modules You also need to change
that portion from settings.py file Like You have changed the module name from your project folder `project1`  to `project1_scrapy` so you also have to change   SPIDER_MODULES = ['`project1_scrapy`.spiders']

[image: Project structure]

If you don't change anything then, Your project folders structure in vscode would be as above screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `SPIDER_MODULES` of `project1/project1_scrapy/settings.py` to make the scrapy search for the correct directory for the spider

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#spider-modules

For your case,

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ["project1_scrapy.spiders"]
```